# fill down header interior color to last row in used range?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some code in order to filldown header interior colors to only the lastrow in my used range. It works fine, but I feel like there has to be a more elegant way of doing this instead of having this massive block of code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillColors()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("Template.xlsx")
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rng As range



    With wb.Sheets("File")

    lastrow = .range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .range("AH3:AI" & lastrow).Interior.Color = .range("AH2:AI2").Interior.Color
    .range("AJ3:AL" & lastrow).Interior.Color = .range("AJ2:AL2").Interior.Color
    .range("AM3:AN" & lastrow).Interior.Color = .range("AM2:AN2").Interior.Color
    .range("AO3:AO" & lastrow).Interior.Color = .range("AO2").Interior.Color
    .range("AX3:AX" & lastrow).Interior.Color = .range("AX2").Interior.Color
    .range("AY3:AY" & lastrow).Interior.Color = .range("AY2").Interior.Color
    .range("BC3:BD" & lastrow).Interior.Color = .range("BC2:BD2").Interior.Color
    .range("BF3:BF" & lastrow).Interior.Color = .range("BF2").Interior.Color
    .range("BG3:BG" & lastrow).Interior.Color = .range("BG2").Interior.Color
    .range("BK3:BL" & lastrow).Interior.Color = .range("BK2:BL2").Interior.Color

    Set rng = .range("A3:BP" & lastrow)

        With rng.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = vbBlack
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With

    End With



End Sub
```

Is there an easier way of doing this by implementing an `if cell.interior <> blank Then filldown interior` or something like that?

Comment: Code that works well but leaves you with a bad taste is likely better of posted on [codereview.se]. That said, `AH:AN` looks like contiguous ranges, why not do `AH3:AN" & lastrow`? What is the `Interior.Color` you're copying over? Is it the same for all these cells? Consider including a screenshot of your worksheet, and give reviewers as much context as possible.

Comment: Also unclear why you're asking about a conditional, when there's nothing conditional in your working code.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no real pattern to the columns (that I can see) you need something to set them up to loop or make them unique.

In your case, it might make sense to name the columns you want to change. Then use intersect/usedrange to make changes in one motion.

Example:

```
Sub quickExample()
Const theNamedRanged As String = "Bang"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, changrange As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("file")

    Set changrange = Intersect(ws.Range("A2:zz999999"), ws.Range(theNamedRanged), ws.UsedRange)

    'then do what you need with the range.
    changerange.Interior.Color = xlBOOM

End Sub
```